# Not able to disable lint rule 9044 & 954

Tags: lint, misra

I need to disable below lint warnings as I think, implementation is correct and deviating from this rule will not create any issue.

> Lint: 9044 function parameter modified [MISRA 2012 Rule 17.8,
>   advisory]
>
> Lint: 954 Pointer variable 'p_Config' of type
>   'TLEX_ModeSupply_M_S_CTRL_Reg_Type *' (line 373) could be declared as
>   pointing to const [MISRA 2012 Rule 8.13, advisory]

I tried different below options to disable the warning, however, I didn't get success. How do I disable these warnings?

```
1)
/*lint !e9044 */

2)
/*lint -e{9044} */

3)
/*lint -save -e9044 */
/*lint -restore */
```

Comment: tried with -elib{9044} as well.

Comment: How about you show the code snippet with the reported violation, so we can maybe help?  Otherwise, @LundIn will be along suggesting yu ininstall PClint ;-)